# Equals with row permutation using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to check if two data frames have the same rows.
I've tried:

```
df1.equals(df2)
```

But it returns `False`, because rows are not in the same order. Is there any function which check equals, but with row permutation? Thank You very much for any help.

Comment: `(np.sort(df1) == np.sort(df2)).all().all()`?

Answer (score 1):

In `pandas` the `index` is important , if the index different even all value same in the rows, we should still treat it as different , however we can do `merge`

```
df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='outer')['_merge'].eq('both').all()
```